# How to get output of port scanner program in python to a text file

Tags: python, sockets, file-writing

I am writing a program in python to scan the ports of the host and tell how many of them are open, show the time taken & have also added error handling...

This code is working fine but the problem is it is taking too long to scan all the ports (im talking about the time its taking to generate the full output) like it did not even complete in 1hr, is this normal? or what's wrong here.

secondly, I want the output of this program in a text file... I have tried several methods but none of them did work, one of the methods I tried is written at the end of the code in comment. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, in advance!

Here's the source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import subprocess
import sys
from datetime import datetime

# Clear the screen
subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)

# Ask for input
remoteServer = input("Enter a remote host to scan: ")

# Using the range function to specify ports (here it will scans all ports between 1 and 1024)

# We also put in some error handling for catching errors

try:
    remoteServerIP  = socket.gethostbyname(remoteServer)

    # Prints a banner with info on which host we are about to scan
    print ("-" * 60)
    print ("Please wait, scanning remote host", remoteServerIP)
    print ("-" * 60)

    # Check what time the scan started
    t1 = datetime.now()
    
    for port in range(1,1025):  
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))
        if result == 0:
            print ("Port {}:      Open".format(port))
        sock.close()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("You pressed Ctrl+C")
    sys.exit()

except socket.gaierror:
    print ('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
    sys.exit()

except socket.error:
    print ("Host is not available")
    sys.exit()

# Checking the time again
t2 = datetime.now()

# Calculates the difference of time, to see how long it took to run the script
total =  t2 - t1

# Printing the information to screen
print ('Scanning Completed in: ', total)

'''#Text file
f = open('Hostreport.txt', 'a')
print(port,file=f)
f.close()'''
```

Comment: "I have tried several methods but none of them did work" is not helpful, you know?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What did you try, what didn't work? What was the error you got?

Comment: @AKX I have edited the code with the method i tried mention in comment at the end of code. and problem is that file is blank

Answer (score 0):

Two common ways to write simple text to a file in python:

```
with open('/tmp/foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('first line\n')
    f.write('second line\n')
```

Using `open` as a [context manager](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/) means it's only valid *within* the block and python automatically takes care of ensuring it's properly closed at the end.

Or the classic way:

```
f = open('/tmp/bar.txt', 'w')
f.write('first line\n')
f.write('second line\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: where shall I add this in order to get output in text file?